# Creating node module half-native half-js

Tags: node.js

I have made a module for Node.js, which is part native, a C++ compiled library and half-JavaScript - about 10 *.js files. How should I distribute that? As single module or separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the use case I suppose, but as one module is probably fine. Unless you'd like to maintain them in separate repositories, you've got other modules that might prefer depending on them separately, or other otherwise and then it is just a matter of adding one to the other's package.json dependency list.